# Inline Date Picker in static TableView has blank stripes

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, xcode7

I'm using Xcode 7 and added a Date Picker to a static cell within a TableView via the Storyboard editor. Everything looks fine so far,  but when it's rendered either in the simulator or the iPhone it shows vertical blank stripes in the Date Picker. In the example it should say September, but only the Se and r are visible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqo6L.png

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Are you placed this in a tableView ?

Comment: Yes, it's a static table in a UITableView